# Running Tesseract OCR SDK Server Side, with Spring Framework, on Amazon Web Services

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, tesseract

I'm a newbie programmer working on a toy Spring project. I would like run OCR recognition on documents, and then mark them up by overlaying on the original image.  I've chosen to use Tesseract OCR, the Spring Framework, and Amazon Web Services to host the project.  Here are my questions:

1) Whats the best way to include a third party library, like Tesseract OCR with the Spring Framework? Can I just include in the libs folder or will I have to do more with configuration.

2) Is it possible to seperate processing into a web server and application server on AWS?  I would like to process the images on a seperate server instance.  With elastic loading, should I even have to do this?

If you know good introductory texts for the Spring Framework, I'd love to know about them.  Spring is really cool, but its got a steep learning curve!

Thank you